# PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix for mysql-connector-python

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

How can I fix this error? I need to use Anaconda Python 3.6.

```
dhcp-wifi-8021x-155-41-106-41:~ Tkixi$ conda update jupyter numpy mysql-connector-python scipy

PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
  prefix: /Users/Tkixi/anaconda
  package name: mysql-connector-python


dhcp-wifi-8021x-155-41-106-41:~ Tkixi$ conda list
# packages in environment at /Users/Tkixi/anaconda:
#
_license                  1.1                      py36_1  
alabaster                 0.7.10                   py36_0  
anaconda                  custom                   py36_0  
anaconda-client           1.6.3                    py36_0  
anaconda-navigator        1.6.2                    py36_0  
anaconda-project          0.6.0                    py36_0  
appnope                   0.1.0                    py36_0  
appscript                 1.0.1                    py36_0  
asn1crypto                0.22.0                   py36_0  
astroid                   1.4.9                    py36_0  
astropy                   1.3.2               np112py36_0  
babel                     2.4.0                    py36_0  
backports                 1.0                      py36_0  
beautifulsoup4            4.6.0                    py36_0  
bitarray                  0.8.1                    py36_0  
blaze                     0.10.1                   py36_0  
bleach                    1.5.0                    py36_0  
bokeh                     0.12.5                   py36_1  
boto                      2.46.1                   py36_0  
bottleneck                1.2.1               np112py36_0  
cffi                      1.10.0                   py36_0  
chardet                   3.0.3                    py36_0  
click                     6.7                      py36_0  
cloudpickle               0.2.2                    py36_0  
clyent                    1.2.2                    py36_0  
colorama                  0.3.9                    py36_0  
conda                     4.3.25                   py36_0  
conda-env                 2.6.0                         0  
contextlib2               0.5.5                    py36_0  
cryptography              1.8.1                    py36_0  
curl                      7.52.1                        0  
cycler                    0.10.0                   py36_0  
cython                    0.25.2                   py36_0  
cytoolz                   0.8.2                    py36_0  
dask                      0.14.3                   py36_1  
datashape                 0.5.4                    py36_0  
decorator                 4.0.11                   py36_0  
distributed               1.16.3                   py36_0  
docutils                  0.13.1                   py36_0  
entrypoints               0.2.2                    py36_1  
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                    py36_0  
fastcache                 1.0.2                    py36_1  
flask                     0.12.2                   py36_0  
flask-cors                3.0.2                    py36_0  
freetype                  2.5.5                         2  
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                    py36_0  
gevent                    1.2.1                    py36_0  
greenlet                  0.4.12                   py36_0  
h5py                      2.7.0               np112py36_0  
hdf5                      1.8.17                        1  
heapdict                  1.0.0                    py36_1  
html5lib                  0.999                    py36_0  
icu                       54.1                          0  
idna                      2.5                      py36_0  
imagesize                 0.7.1                    py36_0  
ipykernel                 4.6.1                    py36_0  
ipython                   5.3.0                    py36_0  
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py36_0  
ipywidgets                6.0.0                    py36_0  
isort                     4.2.5                    py36_0  
itsdangerous              0.24                     py36_0  
jbig                      2.1                           0  
jdcal                     1.3                      py36_0  
jedi                      0.10.2                   py36_2  
jinja2                    2.9.6                    py36_0  
jpeg                      9b                            0  
jsonschema                2.6.0                    py36_0  
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py36_3  
jupyter_client            5.0.1                    py36_0  
jupyter_console           5.1.0                    py36_0  
jupyter_core              4.3.0                    py36_0  
lazy-object-proxy         1.2.2                    py36_0  
libiconv                  1.14                          0  
libpng                    1.6.27                        0  
libtiff                   4.0.6                         3  
libxml2                   2.9.4                         0  
libxslt                   1.1.29                        0  
llvmlite                  0.18.0                   py36_0  
locket                    0.2.0                    py36_1  
lxml                      3.7.3                    py36_0  
markupsafe                0.23                     py36_2  
matplotlib                2.0.2               np112py36_0  
mistune                   0.7.4                    py36_0  
mkl                       2017.0.1                      0  
mkl-service               1.1.2                    py36_3  
mpmath                    0.19                     py36_1  
msgpack-python            0.4.8                    py36_0  
multipledispatch          0.4.9                    py36_0  
navigator-updater         0.1.0                    py36_0  
nbconvert                 5.1.1                    py36_0  
nbformat                  4.3.0                    py36_0  
networkx                  1.11                     py36_0  
nltk                      3.2.3                    py36_0  
nose                      1.3.7                    py36_1  
notebook                  5.0.0                    py36_0  
numba                     0.33.0              np112py36_0  
numexpr                   2.6.2               np112py36_0  
numpy                     1.12.1                   py36_0  
numpydoc                  0.6.0                    py36_0  
odo                       0.5.0                    py36_1  
olefile                   0.44                     py36_0  
openpyxl                  2.4.7                    py36_0  
openssl                   1.0.2l                        0  
packaging                 16.8                     py36_0  
pandas                    0.20.1              np112py36_0  
pandocfilters             1.4.1                    py36_0  
partd                     0.3.8                    py36_0  
path.py                   10.3.1                   py36_0  
pathlib2                  2.2.1                    py36_0  
patsy                     0.4.1                    py36_0  
pep8                      1.7.0                    py36_0  
pexpect                   4.2.1                    py36_0  
pickleshare               0.7.4                    py36_0  
pillow                    4.1.1                    py36_0  
pip                       9.0.1                    py36_1  
ply                       3.10                     py36_0  
prompt_toolkit            1.0.14                   py36_0  
psutil                    5.2.2                    py36_0  
ptyprocess                0.5.1                    py36_0  
py                        1.4.33                   py36_0  
pycosat                   0.6.2                    py36_0  
pycparser                 2.17                     py36_0  
pycrypto                  2.6.1                    py36_6  
pycurl                    7.43.0                   py36_2  
pyflakes                  1.5.0                    py36_0  
pygments                  2.2.0                    py36_0  
pylint                    1.6.4                    py36_1  
pyodbc                    4.0.16                   py36_0  
pyopenssl                 17.0.0                   py36_0  
pyparsing                 2.1.4                    py36_0  
pyqt                      5.6.0                    py36_1  
pytables                  3.3.0               np112py36_0  
pytest                    3.0.7                    py36_0  
python                    3.6.2                         0  
python-dateutil           2.6.0                    py36_0  
python.app                1.2                      py36_4  
pytz                      2017.2                   py36_0  
pywavelets                0.5.2               np112py36_0  
pyyaml                    3.12                     py36_0  
pyzmq                     16.0.2                   py36_0  
qt                        5.6.2                         2  
qtawesome                 0.4.4                    py36_0  
qtconsole                 4.3.0                    py36_0  
qtpy                      1.2.1                    py36_0  
readline                  6.2                           2  
requests                  2.14.2                   py36_0  
rope                      0.9.4                    py36_1  
ruamel_yaml               0.11.14                  py36_1  
scikit-image              0.13.0              np112py36_0  
scikit-learn              0.18.1              np112py36_1  
scipy                     0.19.0              np112py36_0  
seaborn                   0.7.1                    py36_0  
setuptools                27.2.0                   py36_0  
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py36_1  
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py36_0  
sip                       4.18                     py36_0  
six                       1.10.0                   py36_0  
snowballstemmer           1.2.1                    py36_0  
sortedcollections         0.5.3                    py36_0  
sortedcontainers          1.5.7                    py36_0  
sphinx                    1.5.6                    py36_0  
spyder                    3.1.4                    py36_0  
sqlalchemy                1.1.9                    py36_0  
sqlite                    3.13.0                        0  
statsmodels               0.8.0               np112py36_0  
sympy                     1.0                      py36_0  
tblib                     1.3.2                    py36_0  
terminado                 0.6                      py36_0  
testpath                  0.3                      py36_0  
tk                        8.5.18                        0  
toolz                     0.8.2                    py36_0  
tornado                   4.5.1                    py36_0  
traitlets                 4.3.2                    py36_0  
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py36_0  
unixodbc                  2.3.4                         0  
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py36_0  
werkzeug                  0.12.2                   py36_0  
wheel                     0.29.0                   py36_0  
widgetsnbextension        2.0.0                    py36_0  
wrapt                     1.10.10                  py36_0  
xlrd                      1.0.0                    py36_0  
xlsxwriter                0.9.6                    py36_0  
xlwings                   0.10.4                   py36_0  
xlwt                      1.2.0                    py36_0  
xz                        5.2.2                         1  
yaml                      0.1.6                         0  
zict                      0.1.2                    py36_0  
zlib                      1.2.8                         3
```

Comment: I solved this issue by using `conda env update` rather than `conda update`

Answer (score 5):

I can't find the package named mysql-connector-python from your conda list.
Just try to install mysql-connector-python package first.

```
$ conda install mysql-connector-python 
$ conda update mysql-connector-python
```

or try to give 'name' parameter when you want to install the package for your virtual environment.

```
$ conda install mysql-connector-python --name VENV_NAME
$ conda update mysql-connector-python --name VENV_NAME
```